# Get mat-select selected object (without selecting a different one)

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my solution, I'm having a mat-select bound to a form containing the object's ID. The object is matched via ID (similar to this minimal reproduction: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-11-material-reactive-starter-jdosut?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Now I'd like to get the actual selected object every time the user changes it or even if the control matches it from its initial value.

Sure, I could crawl the array for the object again. But mat-select already does this for me, so is there maybe any easy way to achieve this?

The minimal reproduction is pretty simplified. In my scenario, the control is bound to an observable from outside my component. I could bind the object instead of the object bound by its ID. But in this case, I would need to deliver the whole looping and matching logic that mat-select does here for me. And on selecting an item, I'd need to update the form's value. Pretty much overhead.

I just want to show some further details of the selected option, even if the option hasn't changed. Just going via a UI-variable would be pretty messy, too, since I need to pass the selected object to a dialog.

This seems to be a similar problem ([Angular: Get value from mat select based id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67691284/angular-get-value-from-mat-select-based-id)) with a pretty unsatisfying outcome.

Comment: wait, why you did not use `{{optionId}}` instead of printing `{{selectedOption}}`? and maintaining that value manually. [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-11-material-reactive-starter-gubbr4)

Comment: I've adopted my question a bit, does this help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the whole object as selected value, instead just mapping to the id of the object.

```
<mat-select
    [(ngModel)]="option"
    (selectionChange)="selectedOption = $event.value"
  >
    <mat-option *ngFor="let o of options$ | async" [value]="o">
      {{ o.value }}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

```
option = this.options$.value[1];
selectedOption: any = this.option;
```

[Stack demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-11-material-reactive-starter-qp1axt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: But this way I can't bind my objekt to the form. Or need to listen to change events to set the value.

Comment: I didn't get what you meant with your comment. If you are saying you are working with reactive form, and this field needs to bind a control of the form, then please add your code to the question, so that we clearly see what's going on. My answer was based on the stackblitz you created, which has no usage of reactive form.